# Which of these should be the better approach to write JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Which should be the better approach to write JavaScript code, and why?

1)

```
var myClass = function(){}

myClass.prototype.init = function(x, y){
    this.width = x;
    this.height = y;
}

myClass.prototype.show = function(){
    alert("width = "+ this.width+" height = "+ this.height);
}
```

2)

```
var myObj = {
    init : function(x, y)
    {
        this.width = x;
        this.height = y;
    },
    show : function()
    {
        alert("width = "+ this.width+" height = "+ this.height);    
    }           
}
```

Comment: Markdown doesn't handle lists followed by code correctly, never has...edited slightly to get proper formatting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have are 2 totally different things, the first is a way to create a "class" of object, you can have *many* instances, the second is a single object...so they serve very different purposes.

Do you need many objects, all with their own properties? then the first is a must (there are many forms of this when it comes to inheritance, etc...but the basic `function` structure is what I mean).

Do you need just one object with some variables/methods? then go with the second.

Comment: Is it like a anonymous class, living only in one instance??

Comment: @Simon - the second is a named object, `myNewClass`...which really is a bad name, since it's not a class, it's just an instance on object.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I just want to know one more thing... is this difference related to memory consumption also?

Comment: @Bhupi - Yeah sure, since the first can have many copies and the second is singular it'll use the least memory.  On the first the `.prototype` properties/functions will be shared, so you save memory there, but only after a few are created, until a few are using it, you're actually using *more* memory by hooking them up through prototype...but that is the correct way if you want multiple instances.

Comment: An example: if you write a class to encapsulate utility functions, you just need one instance (e.g. `HTML` which has `HTML.encode()` and `HTML.decode()`). If you write a class to encapsulate information, you need as many instances as items you want (e.g. `Product` which has `Product.setPrice()` and `Product.getPrice()`).